# Equivalent in VB.NET to Add objects of T to a List(of T)

Tags: .net, vb.net, ienumerable

This is my class

```
Public Class DBServer
    Public  ServerId  As Integer
    Public  ServerName As String
End Class
```

And Variable:

```
Dim serverList As New List(Of DBServer)
```

in C#. I can add like this:

`serverList.Add(new DBServer{ ServerId=1,ServerName="Server1"});`

How can I achieve this in VB.NET. I am using .NET 4.0.

Comment: Is `ServerName` supposed to be a String array?

Comment: What have you tried?  There are online C# to Visual Basic .NET converters you can use.  The syntax would nearly be identical I suggest looking at the MSDN VB.NET examples for List<T>

Comment: actually it is not array. I tried and I got a conversion . but throws compilation error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a direct port, try

```
serverList.Add(new DBServer With { .ServerId=1,.ServerName="Server1"})
```

See [Object Initializers: Named and Anonymous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx) for more

Comment: @ken2k: Sorry I haven't compiled it, I translated it from memory. Is there a problem?

Comment: @ken2k: Just checked, builds correctly and works as expected :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct direct translation from C# assuming that `ServerName` **is** actually a String array as posted (Note the extra curly brackets around the `Servername` initialiser):

```
serverlist.Add(New DBServer() With {.ServerId = 1, .ServerName = {"foo"}})
```

If Servername is **not** a string array and is in fact a string then @Binary Worrier has the correct solution:

```
serverlist.Add(New DBServer() With {.ServerId = 1, .ServerName = "foo"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a List with an Enumerable (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0)

```
    Dim serverList As New List(Of DBServer)({New DBServer With {.ServerId = 1, .ServerName = "Server One"},
                                             New DBServer With {.ServerId = 2, .ServerName = "Server Two"},
                                             New DBServer With {.ServerId = 3, .ServerName = "Server Three"}})
```

Comment: This cause Compile error. saying that we are giving one dimenstional array

Comment: Runs fine my side.  I suspect its actually because your property "ServerName" is an array of string rather than just a string.

Comment: actually it a string only not the array

Comment: Now that you've edited your question it is.  See Matt Wilko answer. With your update my example should be fine.